# Problem with bouncing out to QT

Tags: bounce, sync, pro-tools

The clip I'm trying to bounce out is 25 FPS and I have both timecodes and feet+frames rate at 25 FPS, but every single time I bounce to disk in PT 10 the audio drifts about one or two seconds behind the video. Anyone ever have this problem or know how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Confirm that your session is in the right frame rate (Session Setup window). Also make sure that you don't have any pull-up or pull down enabled (same window); you only need to do that if you're bouncing to a different frame rate than your session.

Comment: @Shaun Farley Ha! I took off the audio pull up and it works now. When I set my FPS to 25 it seemed to set the audio pull up automatically, so I figured it was correct. Thanks Shaun.

Answer (score 0):

How long is the total bounce? Can you try bouncing it in shorter reels, then combining it afterwards?

Comment: @Max H. It's only 15 seconds long. 

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 possibilities.  First are you referencing to PAL or a 25 frame HD ref source?  Second on the Session Setup page do you have your Video Ref Format set to PAL?  The answer to both should be yes but having either one set improperly could cause sync problems.

Comment: @Mike Fisher When I imported the video in PT it says it's 25FPS. It has a Timecode (yet not actual timecode), and Apple ProRes 422 HQ codecs. I have session setup page to Audio 4% up. Does this sound correct?

Comment: And when I bounce out to Quicktime should I be doing 46080 Film to PAL?

Comment: @Mitchell Scott, Sorry for the delay. I hope this is in time to help you. I don't see why you would need the 4% change if everything is set to 25. Also, because of the sample rate change, this may be why your audio is out of sync. Pro-tools may not accurately do the pull down through the "bounce to quicktime movie" function.  